# How to send and receive secret key using datagram socket

Tags: java, sockets, udp, datagram, des

Im trying to make a simple des chat system, but I have a problem receiving secret key in udp. The error message shows the problem with objectInputStream.

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 358A822E
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:806)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:299)
```

this is the sender code

```
InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
KeyGenerator keygenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DES");
SecretKey myDesKey = keygenerator.generateKey();
Cipher desCipher;

// Create the cipher
desCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");

// Initialize the cipher for encryption
desCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, myDesKey);

ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
oos.writeObject((Object) myDesKey);
oos.flush();
final byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();

DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(bytes, bytes.length, inetAddress, 999);
socket.send(sendPacket);
```

this is the reciever code

```
   Cipher desCipher;
SecretKey myDesKey = null;
// Create the cipher

desCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");

packetIn = new DatagramPacket(dataOut, dataOut.length);
socket.receive(packetIn);
ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(packetIn.getData());
ObjectInputStream oos = new ObjectInputStream(bais);
myDesKey = (SecretKey) oos.readObject();
System.out.println("the key is " + myDesKey.toString());
desCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, myDesKey);
```

Comment: This is not secure. You are sending the secret key as plaintext. Maybe you should be using PKI to send it? NB it should be `new ByteArrayInputStream(packetIn.getData(), 0, packet.getLength())`.

Comment: (I would say you received something else other than the key.)